# Add age adjustment to geom_smooth

Tags: r, static-methods, adjustment

I need to include age adjustment in the geom_smooth line I am adding to my ggscatter plot.

my data looks like~
[table link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4Bjp.png)

```
structure(list(Time = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 12L, 18L, 18L, 0L, 
12L, 18L, 6L), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), 
    Age = c(77, 70.2, 69.9, 65.7, 66.2, 66.7, 67.2, 67.7, 66.8, 
    67.8, 68.3, 68.8), Average = c(96L, 90L, 94L, 94L, 96L, 96L, 
    92L, 120L, 114L, 109L, 113L, 103L)), row.names = c(NA, 12L
), class = "data.frame")
```

What I currently have (the 'Average" value have dependency in age..):

```
ggscatter(dtable, "Time","Average",conf.int = TRUE)+theme_bw()+
geom_smooth(aes(group=1),method='lm')+facet_wrap(~groups)
```

**What I would like to have is something like:**

```
ggscatter(dtable, "Time","Average",conf.int = TRUE)+theme_bw()+
geom_smooth(aes(group=1),method='lm', adjust= ~age)+facet_wrap(~groups)
```

With adjustment per each group mean age

Any suggestions?

Comment: you can run a `lm` and then use the predict function to append linear values onto your data set and then plot those. if you share your code I can show you.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a sample table.
I 'm not sure in which part I should add the predict function and how to make sure its divided by group.  Should I create a 'formula' separately and insert it to geom_smooth?

Comment: Hi @BarrMorgenstein, instead of a link to a photo, try `dput(head(your_data, 20))` and then put that output in the post. It will help with problem solving.

Comment: @MDEWITT  - added :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is I think what you are after.

First, we need to fit the more complicated model because ggplot does not have a functionality for multivariable models (yet)

```
fit <- lm(Average ~ Time + group + Age, data = tdata)
```

Then we can use some functionality from the broom package to add the predictions and associated standard errors. With these in hand we can manually build the plot using the geom_line and geom_ribbon geoms

```
library(broom)
tdata %>% 
  bind_cols(augment(fit)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Time, Average))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line(aes(x = Time, y = .fitted), size = 2, color = "blue")+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = .fitted + .se.fit*2, ymax = .fitted - .se.fit*2), alpha = .2)+
  facet_wrap(~group)+
  theme_bw()
```

Additionally, if you wanted to look at pooled vs non-pooled estimates

```
fit_no_pool <- lm(Average ~ Time + group + Age, data = tdata)
fit_complete_pool <- lm(Average ~ Time + Age, data = tdata)

library(broom)
tdata %>% 
  bind_cols(augment(fit_no_pool) %>% setNames(sprintf("no_pool%s", names(.)))) %>% 
  bind_cols(augment(fit_complete_pool) %>% setNames(sprintf("pool%s", names(.)))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Time, Average))+
  geom_point()+
  # Non-Pooled Estimates
  geom_line(aes(x = Time, y = no_pool.fitted, color = "blue"), size = 2)+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = no_pool.fitted + no_pool.se.fit*2, 
                  ymax = no_pool.fitted - no_pool.se.fit*2), alpha = .2)+
  # Pooled Estimates
  geom_line(aes(x = Time, y = pool.fitted, color = "orange"), size = 2)+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = pool.fitted + pool.se.fit*2, 
                  ymax = pool.fitted - pool.se.fit*2), alpha = .2)+
  facet_wrap(~group)+
  scale_color_manual(name = "Regression", 
                       labels = c("Pooled", "Non-Pooled"), 
                     values = c("blue", "orange"))+
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: he wants an Age adjustment and faceted by group - it might be worth putting both age and group in the model in the real data if it will be faceted by group

Comment: Thank you! It works!


Just one last question if possible -before the adjustment I was using a simple linear regression line and evaluated the slops- is there a way I can get the slopes created here or the percent decrease over time?

Comment: Do you mean extract the parameter estimates? You can do that by `summary(fit)` or `broom::tidy(fit)`.

Comment: @MDEWITT - I tried to run the table both the fit including the +groups than faceting and also a subset of the table without the +groups in the fit- the results seems to be different..

Answer (score 0):

One way to go is to run your model with Age as an additional predictor in your model. then use `predict` to get the predicted value with CIs. Append to your data then use ggplot to plot. I know you want to facet by `group`, so it might be worth putting it into your model as well. Just a thought. The steps would be the same.

```
df <- structure(list(Time = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 12L, 18L, 18L, 0L, 
    12L, 18L, 6L), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), 
    Age = c(77, 70.2, 69.9, 65.7, 66.2, 66.7, 67.2, 67.7, 66.8, 
    67.8, 68.3, 68.8), Average = c(96L, 90L, 94L, 94L, 96L, 96L, 
    92L, 120L, 114L, 109L, 113L, 103L)), row.names = c(NA, 12L
    ), class = "data.frame")


#model adjusted for age
mod <- lm(Average ~ Time + Age, data = df)
#get prediction with CIS
premod <- predict(mod, interval = "predict")
#append to data
df2 <- cbind(df,premod)
#add prediction to ggplot with scatter plot
ggplot(df2) + 
    geom_point(aes(x=Time,y=Average)) +
    geom_line(aes(x=Time, y = fit)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(x = Time,ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), alpha = .1)+
    facet_wrap(~group)+
    theme_bw()
```